AttributeError при взаимодействии с атрибутом year из класса предка (у класса есть этот атрибут)
Это весь код моей программы:
import datetime

class Human:
    ''' 
        Класс: Human, Родитель
        методы: changeName, calcAge
        Описание: Класс описывает свойства объекта человек. (name, year)
    '''
    # Конструктор
    def __init__(self, name="", year=0) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.year = year

    # Метод changeName изменяет имя пользователя
    def changeName(self, userName) -> None:
        self.name = userName
        print(f"Имя измененно на {userName}")

    # Метод calcAge вычисляет возраст пользователя
    def calcAge(self) -> int: 
        age = datetime.date.today().year - self.year
        return age

class Student(Human):
    ''' 
        Класс: Student, Ребёнок
        методы: changeCourse, nextCourse
        Описание: Класс описывает свойства студента. (course)
    '''
    # Конструктор 
    def __init__(self, course=1) -> None:
        self.course = course

    # Метод changeCourse изменяет года обучения 
    def changeCourse(self, userCourse) -> str:
        if (17 >= self.calcAge() <= 27): self.course = userCourse
        else: return print(f"{self.name} не входит в возрастную катигорию") 

    # Метод nextCourse переводи студента на следующий курс
    def nextCourse(self) -> str:
        self.course += 1
        if (self.course == 5): return print(f"{self.name} закончил/закончила обучение")

human1 = Human(name="Лёша", year=2008)
human2 = Human(name="Маша", year=2008)

student1 = Student(2)
student2 = Student(1)

print("\nТест на смену имени")

student1.changeName("Ваня")
student2.changeName("Соня")

print(student1.name)
print(student2.name)

print("\nТест на изменение курса")

print(f"{student1.year} на {student1.course} курсе\n{student2.name} на {student2.course} курсе")

student1.changeCourse(3)

print(f"{student1.name} на {student1.course} курсе\n{student2.name} на {student2.course} курсе")

В Human.calcAge() я использую year для вычисления возраста. Я использую этот метод в классе-наследнике Student, чтобы получить возраст экземпляра.
Но при использовании этого метода внутри класса-наследника происходит исключение:

AttributeError: 'Student' object has no attribute 'year'.

Причём с атрибутом name всё нормально: я ссылаюсь на него от экзмепляров student1 и student2 в 55, 56, 60 и 64 строке.
Я хотел решить свою проблему используя метод super(), но при его использовании атрибут year равен нулю, чему он, собственно, равен по умолчанию:
def __init__(self, course=1) -> None:
    super().__init__()
    self.course = course;


Вам нужно из класса потомка вызвать метод инициализации класса предка с необходимыми параметрами: super.init(self, name="Лёша", year=2008). В вашем варианте класс предок инициализировался значениями по умолчанию. Странно, об этом в каждой книге про Python написано.

Пардон, правильно будет super.init(name="Лёша", year=2008) без self. Существует альтернативный способ: Human.init(self, name="Лёша", year=2008), в котором self нужен.

Я понимаю это и тогда мне нужно будет в экземпляре класса Student передать значение атрибутов name и year, чего я делать не хочу. Требуется, чтобы метод calcAge брался из класса Human и атрибуты name и year передавались в экземпляре класса Human следующим образом: human = Human(name="name", year=2009). Если у нас атрибуты класса Human будут не по умолчанию, возможно ли такое реализовать?

Звучит конечно странно, что родительский класс и потомок инициализируются сами по себе при живом то наследовании. На вскидку можно предложить добавить отдельный метод для изменения года подобно changeName, или вообще убрать наследование и создавать экземпляр класса Human прямо внутри Student и получать доступ к методам Human через свойства класса Student.

Кстати, еще идея. Создать декоратор для класса Student, который сам инициализируется значениями name и year и передает эти параметры классу Human через метод init. Тогда внешне создание экземпляра класса Student будет выглядеть как обычно без name и year, но за кулисами декоратор их проинициализирует.

Извиняюсь, проблема в моём задании и, скорее всего, его понимании мной. Там требуется создать класс Human с полями name и year, методом calcAge, который вычисляет возраст. И создать потомка от класса Human (Student), чтобы тот наследовал его атрибуты и методы. И при этом, при создании экземпляра класса Student мы должны брать атрибуты и методы именно из Human, как я говорил ранее. Могу скинуть вам задание, если интересно.

Увы, в том и проблема, что метод calcAge только вычисляет возраст человека. Невозможно инициализировать её внутри этого метода.

Так проблема не в методах. Можно хоть все методы поместить в Human, а Student оставить только с одним init. Проблема с порядком инициализации атрибутов. Поймите, вы создаете атрибуты через self, а это означает, что они будут существовать в либо в экземпляру Human, если вы его отдельно создаете, либо в экземпляре Student. Даже когда вы корректно вызываете из Student метод super().init, то Human создаст атрибуты year и name в экземпляре Student через получаемый self, а не у себя, как это может показаться. Кстати, метод changeName создает атрибут name тоже в Student.

Еще вариант, сделать из Human класс-фабрику, который создает пустые экземпляры Student. Потом вызвать либо отдельный метод для доинициализации экземпляра Student, либо задействовать метод call в Student для доинициализации.

Поправка, не класс-фабрику, а функцию фабрику

Как будто больше проблема не в коде, а в подходе к решению. Мы создаём студента, но не создаём ему имя и год? Немного не логично, на мой взгляд. У него есть курс, но нет имени и года. Без негатива)

Вы были на правильном пути - для инициализации атрибутов родительского класса в наследнике можно использовать super().__init__()
В такой __init__ аналогично можно передать аргументы (как year). Причем наиболее кратко (без повторения аргументов) это можно сделать с помощью *args и **kwargs - конструкций для приёма неопределенного количества позиционных и именованных аргументов.
Указываем их для приёма в наследнике, а потом передаем в метод родительского класса:
class Human:
    def __init__(self, name="", year=0) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.year = year

class Student(Human):
    # используем **kwargs, т.к. в родительском классе именованные аргументы
    def __init__(self, course=1, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.course = course


student1 = Student(course=2, year=2008)

print(student1.year)
print(student1.__dict__)  # магический метод __dict__ показывает все атрибуты

Вывод:
2008
{'name': '', 'year': 2008, 'course': 2}

Но можно и прямо прописать аргументы для приема, продублировав их:
class Human:
    def __init__(self, name="", year=0) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.year = year

class Student(Human):
    def __init__(self, course=1, name="", year=0) -> None:
        super().__init__(name, year)
        self.course = course


Требуется, чтобы атрибут year получал своё значение именно в экземпляре human.
human = Human(name="", year=2008)
В вашем варианте установление значения для поля year происходит в экземпляре класса Student, что мне не очень подходит:
student1 = Student(course=2, year=2008)
Почему нельзя просто сослаться на метод calcAge? Ведь, насколько я понял, класс-потомок наследует все методы и атрибуты класса предка.

Когда вы делаете: human = Human(name="", year=2008), вы создаете отдельный независимый экземпляр класса Human, никак не связанный с Student. Атрибут name создается в экземпляре класса Student во время вызова метода changeName. Атрибут year инициализируется только в классе Human. Без super()init атрибут year вообще не создается, с пустым супер year создается с дефолтовым значением.

Такой вариант подойдет? Останется только методы добавить.
class Human:
    def __init__(self, name="", year=0) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.year = year

class Student(Human):
    def __init__(self, course=1, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.course = course

def human(name="", year=0):
    _name = name
    _year = year
    def student(course=1):
        return Student(course=course, name=_name, year=_year)
    return student

human1 = human(name="Лёша", year=2008)
student1 = human1(course=2)
student2 = human(name="Маша", year=2008)(course=1)
print(student1.name, student1.year, student1.course)
print(student2.name, student2.year, student2.course)

Еще один вариант:
class Human:
    def __init__(self, name="", year=0) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.year = year
    
    def __call__(self, course=1):
        _student = Student(course=course)
        setattr(_student,'name',self.name)
        setattr(_student,'year',self.year)
        return _student

class Student(Human):
    def __init__(self, course=1) -> None:
        self.course = course

human1 = Human(name="Лёша", year=2008)
student1 = human1(course=2)
student2 = Human(name="Маша", year=2008)(course=1)
print(student1.name, student1.year, student1.course)
print(student2.name, student2.year, student2.course)

Если кровь из носу нужно хранить name и year в классе Human:
class Human:
    def __init__(self, name="", year=0) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.year = year
        self._self = self
    
    def __call__(self, course=1):
        _student = Student(course=course)
        setattr(_student,'human',self._self)
        return _student

class Student(Human):
    def __init__(self, course=1) -> None:
        self.course = course

    @property
    def name(self):
        _name = ''
        if hasattr(self,'human'):
            _name = self.human.name
        return _name

    @property
    def year(self):
        _year = 0
        if hasattr(self,'human'):
            _year = self.human.year
        return _year

human1 = Human(name="Лёша", year=2008)
student1 = human1(course=2)
student2 = Human(name="Маша", year=2008)(course=1)
print(student1.name, student1.year, student1.course)
print(student2.name, student2.year, student2.course)
human1.year = 2014
print(student1.name, student1.year, student1.course)

